# Magento2: Save data of popup form in database using ajax in controller

Tags: ajax, magento2.3.2, popup

I set button in form popup in product-detail page in addtocart.phtml in my custom module.

But form submit button is not working and data not passed to controller so not saved in the database

Here is my code.

addtocart.phtml file:

```
 <div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">    
  <form method="post" id="quote_form" action=<?php echo $block->getUrl('quote/index/addquotedata');?>>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $_product->getName();?>">
  <label>Quantity</label>
  <input type="number" name="quote_qty" id="quote_qty">

  <label>price</label>
  <input type="text" name="quote_price" id="quote_price">
  <label>description</label>
  <input type="text" name="quote_desc" id="quote_desc">

  <!-- <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">submit</button> -->
 </form>
</div>


<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function($,modal) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Product Question',
                closeText: 'Close',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Submit'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function (data) {

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php  echo $block->getBaseUrl().'quote/index/addquotedata/';?>",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data : {product_name :name,quote_qty:quote_qty,quote_price:quote_price,quote_desc:quote_desc}                    
                       });

                        // this.closeModal();

                    }
                }]              

            };
           var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click', function () {
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

And this is my Controller file

```
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Infy\Quotesystem\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory;

    class Addquotedata extends Action {

        protected $request;
        protected $collectionFactory;
        protected $_pageFactory;
        protected $_resulFactory;
        protected $customerResourceFactory;

        public function __construct(Context $context, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resulFactory,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory) {

            $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
            $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
            $this->_resultFactory = $resulFactory;
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute() {

            $pageFactory = $this->_pageFactory->create();

            $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quote_qty',null);        
            $price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quote_price',null); 
            $desc = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quote_desc',null);
            $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_name',null);
            $std = $this->_objectManager->create('Infy\Quotesystem\Model\ResourceModel\Post');

             $std->setProductQuantity($qty);
            $std->setQuotePrice($price);
            $std->setQuoteDescription($desc);
            $std->setProductName($name);
             echo "Inserted Data";
            $std->save();
            if($std->save())
           {
                //$this->_redirect('students/index/stdinfo');
           }
        }
    }
```

It gives error in console: Uncaught TypeError:

```
Illegal invocation

at add (jquery.js:10073)

at buildParams (jquery.js:10061)

at buildParams (jquery.js:10055)

at buildParams (jquery.js:10055)

at Function.jQuery.param (jquery.js:10095)

at Function.ajax (jquery.js:9612)

at $.<computed>.<computed>.click (test.html:490)

at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5226)

at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4878)
```

Comment: please check ajax response or system.log . If any error return then please post here.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: Please add in your question and also post system.log

Comment: There is no system.log